# Excel.Interop unable of progressing after a new instance is initialized

Tags: c#, office-interop, dcom, office-automation

I am sitting with the following issue: after a new instance of Interop.Excel.Application() is initialized, my application hangs without timeout or any other progress/exception, nadda.

A bit of background, it is a brand new installation of `Office 2013` on a `Windows 2012 R2` server. I have got an IIS application pool running under a unique built-in account. This specific account has got full administrative rights on the server. I have added `Local Launch` and `Local Activation` DCOM configuration permissions for this specific user under the `Component Services > Launch and Activation Permissions` section and also created the `Desktop` folder on `System32\config\systemprofile`.

Below is the code I use to instantiate a new instance of Excel:

```
var excelApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
```

On our dev environment, I do not have this issue and I also did not have to specifiy the `DCOM configuration permissions`. The Dev environment is running on a `Windows 2008 R2 Standard` server and Office was also newly installed a couple of weeks ago. Same configuration on IIS applies whereas it is a unique built-in account for the application pool identity.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the IIS custom-account user did not have adequate permissions on the production server. Once the account was updated, it worked.